# Unable to stress NVIDIA GPU

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, gpu-driver

I have a RTX A5000 24GB with 230W TDP. I am unable to stress the GPU on my Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. Whenever I run a machine learning model (4-5GB RAM on GPU) the screen hangs for 4-5 seconds and then the PC restarts. BTW my workstation has a MSI BIOS(UEFI) and there is no integrated Graphics.

I installed Windows 11 on the same SSD (dual-boot), I stressed the GPU to 100% TDP with FurMark v1.31.0.0 GPU stress test benchmark tool and there is no problem. [Here](https://gpuscore.top/furmark/show.php?id=724008) are the results.

I also ran multiple ML models which takes upto 20GB RAM on the GPU. There was no problem.

How is that happening? The problem is somewhat similar to this [one](https://askubuntu.com/q/1270035/1230667).

Here is the output of `nvidia-smi` on both the Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 11 Home 21H2.

```sh
Sat Oct  1 13:20:55 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX A5000    Off  | 00000000:65:00.0  On |                    0 |
| 30%   32C    P8    14W / 230W |    198MiB / 23028MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1459      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 39MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2458      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 55MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2602      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               92MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```sh
Sat Oct  1 12:26:46 2022
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 517.40       Driver Version: 517.40       CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX A5000   WDDM  | 00000000:65:00.0  On |                    0 |
| 30%   42C    P2    64W / 230W |    146MiB / 23028MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      7780    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe         N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8732    C+G   ...artMenuExperienceHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8792    C+G   ...n1h2txyewy\SearchHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     11088    C+G   ...r\MSI_Network_Manager.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     11092    C+G   ...SI\Fast Boot\FastBoot.exe    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I know there some Windows8/10 specific [settings in the BIOS](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1020804/Msi-Z170a-Pc-Mate.html?page=45). But I don't think this is solving the problem by any means on Windows 11.

Comment: I am confused is the issue on Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: on Ubuntu as described in the first paragraph. why would I write a post here if the problem is on Windows. lol

Comment: If it's about Ubuntu, then all the information you've posted about Windows is a distraction for anyone who is reading your post.

Comment: Read the last sentence in you question.

Comment: Apologies. I just added the information because on Windows things are working just fine. I thought may be that information might help in understanding the problem.

Comment: It is useful to know the hardware is working correctly with a different OS.  That eliminates a whole class of potential problems.

Comment: Yes. I agree. This problem is very weird. I can't find anything on Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had long discussion with NVIDIA in a private support ticket. Even they couldn't understand the problem. But we had thing working in the end.

In short, my PSU has 600W power supply. With the same rail for motherboard and GPU (12*46=552W). More details can be found [here](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/which-rail-in-the-psu-is-used-by-the-gpu.3779271/#post-22810749).

After reviewing the crash dump, we unplugged all the displays and connected to the PC using SSH. Than we killed `Xorg` and `GDM`. This time we could stress the GPU.

The crash dump indicated the following:

```sh
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: Xorg: ../../../../dix/privates.c:384: dixRegisterPrivateKey: Assertion `!global_keys[type].created' failed.
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE)
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) Backtrace:
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x13c) [0x55af51a31ddc]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (funlockfile+0x60) [0x7f7b5d0e4420]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (gsignal+0xcb) [0x7f7b5cf1f00b]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (abort+0x12b) [0x7f7b5cefe859]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (?+0x0) [0x7f7b5cefe729]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__assert_fail+0x46) [0x7f7b5cf0ffd6]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (dixRegisterPrivateKey+0x239) [0x55af518eeb39]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (glamor_init+0xcf) [0x7f7b52ce037f]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f7b5cbb1cfd]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f7b5cba9fb6]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (AddGPUScreen+0xf5) [0x55af518d03b5]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xf86PlatformMatchDriver+0xa44) [0x55af5192b4c4]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xf86PlatformDeviceCheckBusID+0x225) [0x55af51930f05]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 13: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (config_fini+0xa4a) [0x55af5192d10a]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 14: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (config_fini+0x1408) [0x55af5192dac8]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 15: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsCleanup+0x5c1) [0x55af51a32831]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 16: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (WaitForSomething+0x193) [0x55af51a2b5f3]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 17: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (SendErrorToClient+0x117) [0x55af518cfd77]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 18: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x3b4) [0x55af518d4064]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 19: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f7b5cf00083]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE) 20: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2e) [0x55af518bdaae]
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE)
 Oct 12 09:21:47 MSI-X299-SLI-PLUS-7A93 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2799]: (EE)
```

NVIDIA concluded that the `Xorg` is crashing in `modesetting_drv` driver. They asked me to contact the Ubuntu support for why Xorg crashing in `modesetting_drv`. I didn't.

NVIDIA recommended me to either switch to Windows or change the motherboard to one with on-board graphics and use it for the display. But I upgraded Ubuntu to 22.04 and used the Wayland which work just fine.

BTW we also tested the new open-source NVIDIA driver, but things were still the same. If anyone needs the complete crash dump(~260MB), I can upload it on wetransfer.